# Embedding an SVG into a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, svg

I haven't found any ways, but I was wondering if there is a way to embed an SVG into a dropdown menu. I've got one SVG already in my HTML and can't seem to even get a dropdown functioning, yet when I write all the JS in something like the 'Tryit Editor' on W3, everything functions but I lack the ability to add the SVG I need to add.

```
    <svg height="100%" width="100%">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad3" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0, 96, 45);stop-opacity:1" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0, 172, 68);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <rect width="930" height="340" fill="url(#grad3)" />
    </svg>
```

There's my SVG code if that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of dropdown menu do you mean? Show the code you have that works that you want to add svg to?

Comment: @ErikDahlström 
Use jQuery .slideDown - .onMouseOver/.onMouseOut.

`<table width="930" height="340">
   <svg here/>
     <tr bgcolor="transparent">
       <td onmouseover="showmenu('core')" onmouseout="hidemenu('core')">
       <a href="">Dept</a><br>
         <table class="menu" id="dept" width="120">
           <tr><td class="menu"><a href="">Eng</a></td></tr>
           <tr><td class="menu"><a href="">Mth</a></td></tr>
           <tr><td class="menu"><a href="">Sci</a></td></tr>
           <tr><td class="menu"><a href="">Soc</a></td></tr>
         </table>
       </td>
     </tr>
 </table>

Comment: Maybe css gradients is a better fit here? Or you could use the svg as the css background-image of the table, if that's what you want.

Comment: @ErikDahlström 
I'll try that, thanks for the help. I know I can't use CSS gradients because they aren't supported, at all, by earlier versions of Firefox, IE, and Opera. The website I'm making is required to be compatible with every major browser too.